# How to limit access to Recycle Bin?

Tags: security, recycle-bin, password-protection

How can I password protect my Recycle Bin so that no one else besides me can recover the files I've "deleted"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each drives of your computer has a hidden folder named **$Recycle.Bin**, they store files or folders temporarily deleted by users. You can protect Recycle Bin by change security these folders.
Try following steps:

1. Open **Folder Options**, show hidden folders.
2. Change security of **Recycle** by right click on this folder icon --> *Properties* --> *Security* tab. Remove all groups or users except *SYSTEM*, *Administrators* group and your user name.

Do these steps for the same folder name in other drives. Hope this help.

Comment: my laptop has single user account. how can i do that?

Comment: set password for your account and don't allow others access your computer

Comment: @rebel - Add another user.

Comment: @DaiNguyen-Van, Hmm, is this the official way to do it?

Comment: True, but remember that people can still recover the files by disk imaging and running a recovery program. The only way to protect yourself from that is to use a tool like "AVG shred", or, if you want it done professionally, nuke your hard disk.